# How to define jpanels to their own class switching between them?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpanel, windowbuilder

Currently making a program that is to access a sql database where the data is viewed on a Jtable with textfields and buttons on the side to alter add and delete data from the database (this is all working).
What I'm troubled with is, I've started making my other jpanels, (currently using one class for all this) and I've found that the amount of lines of code is getting large..

I would like to ask, is it possible define each jpanels content and buttons in their own separate class, and how I would go about doing so.
With that, how would I switch between each jpanel?

Currently using a cardlayout with different japanels. Heres how my UI looks, (not the main jpanel).

[image]

The 5 buttons at the very top of the GUI is supposed to navigate between the jpanels, and the rest of the buttons, textfields and jtables differ depending on the jpanel thats navigated to.

Some of the code within the main class, which has my jpanels:

```
    JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(main_panel, "name_21784032966449");
    main_panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnHome = new JButton("Home");
    btnHome.setBounds(10, 11, 97, 38);
    main_panel.add(btnHome);

    JButton btnHandOver = new JButton("Hand Over");
    btnHandOver.setBounds(117, 11, 97, 38);
    main_panel.add(btnHandOver);

    JButton btnMachineLogs = new JButton("Machine Logs");
    btnMachineLogs.setBounds(224, 11, 97, 38);
    main_panel.add(btnMachineLogs);

    JButton btnParts = new JButton("Parts");
    btnParts.setBounds(10, 60, 97, 38);
    main_panel.add(btnParts);

    JButton btnRunup = new JButton("Run Up");
    btnRunup.setBounds(117, 60, 97, 38);
    main_panel.add(btnRunup);

    JPanel parts_panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(parts_panel, "name_22617526869296");
    parts_panel.setLayout(null);
```

I have no idea how to instead define each jpanel to their own classes, and less for how to make it possible to switch between panels.

Comment: Like, I have a similar thing where I have an advanced search, each "panel" is a field name drop down combobox, a comparison drop down (greater than, less than, etc), and a box to put in your search criteria. You just click a plus button and it adds another panel. Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to define the content of the jpanels in their own jpanels, so i dont have one main class thats flooded with methods, buttons and sql connections, currently ive just got one class  that'll end up with code for about 5 jpanels, and i would rather have them in different classes

Comment: Please edit your image link so that it links to an actual image and not to a web page that holds the image. Also please show pertinent code.

Comment: As for your questions: `"I would like to ask, is it possible define each jpanels content and buttons in their own separate class..."` -- the answer is an unqualified ***yes***, and `"...how I would go about doing so."` -- This would all depend on the details of your current program overall structure and code.

Comment: Well we've got the image now, which I've added, and we have some code, but none of seems to help clarify your problem, at least not for me. If I were you, I'd go ahead and try to create classes for my JPanels and see if I can do it myself, and then if it doesn't work, ask a much more specific question showing code that actually relates to your problem (your current code doesn't). All your current code shows us is that you're using `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` which marks this as newbie Swing code, and that this code would be improved by using layouts.

Comment: Consider searching this site for similar questions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371699/a-individual-class-for-each-card-in-java-swing-cardlayout). Also please check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16096693/522444).

Comment: Hey, [here's an even better dup question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28488649/522444) and provides an example of exactly what you're looking for -- JPanels in separate classes, swapped by a CardLayout.

Comment: Thanks your answer has given me a much clearer idea of how to go about it, I was totally looking at this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hovercraft full of eels, with the link to a previous question and answer:

[CardLayout changing panel from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488458/cardlayout-changing-panel-from-another-class/28488649#28488649)